# bounded monotone sequences converge - why do we need irrational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

we've proved that monotone sequences converge, there is a question afterwards which asks why do we need the completeness axiom for this? Why wouldn't it be true if we didn't have irrational numbers?

I can't seem to answer this, so I feel as though I'm missing something.

Comment: $3.1$, $3.14$, $3.141$, $\ldots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider a series of rational numbers that converge to an irrational number, like the e-series. http://ideallyaddicted.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/non-converging-cauchy-sequences/

Answer (score 1):

To show completeness is necessary, you just need to construct an increasing sequence of rational numbers converging to an irrational number.  There are many ways of doing this, for example:

- Use the decimal expansion of a well-known irrational number, as in David Mitra's comment.
- Use the partial sums of $1 + \frac11 + \frac12 + \frac1{3!} + \cdots = e$.
- Use rational approximations to $\sqrt{2}$.  For each $n$, let $q_n$ be the largest rational number with denominator at most $n$ such that $q_n^2 < 2$.